# What is the use of "const" functions?

Tags: c++, function, constants, function-qualifier

This code looks weird:

```
const double square(double x) {

    return x*x;

}
```

Common sense tells me that `const` in this context means either

- the function returns a `const double`

OR

- it promises not to change the `double` that was passed in. But it was passed in by value! I don't understand

OR

- I know that `const member functions` promise not to change `*this`, but this is not even a member function.

### Edit

What's the point to return a `const double` if you can save the result in a non-`const` variable and edit it??

```
double var = square(4.5); // no compile error

var = 0.3;
```

Comment: This function returns a const double, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense since the calling function can always store the result in a non-const double (the value will be copied). I think some compilers raise warnings regarding that kind of return type.

Comment: *"Common sense tells me ..."*. Please don't use *only* your common sense, that is not enough when learning a programming language (especially C++). Read a good C++ book as well.

Comment: In OOP this means that an class extending the class this function is contained in, cannot override this function.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno: this is not member function, so OOP does not apply

Comment: It's NOT a duplicate! Every other question is about **references**, I'm asking about **returning a constant value**

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno even if it were a member function, what you say would not be correct.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno, You're thinking of `final`.

Comment: The duplicate answers your original question. Your edit poses a different question.

Comment: From my answer to that question: "The const at the beginning means whatever is being returned is const.". It doesn't matter if it is a reference.

Comment: I'd answer this, but I can't, because it is marked as a duplicate.  (It's not, and none of the answers to the questions actually answer this; for the most part, they're not even correct.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is weird. As you say:

> the function returns a `const double`

For a user-defined type, this would prevent you from modifying the return value:

```
square(2) += 5; // Error
```

although, as noted in the comments, this isn't allowed for a built-in type like `double` anyway. Even for user-defined types, while you probably don't want to write code like that, there's no point preventing it either.

For more complicated types, returning a `const` value can actually be harmful: it inhibits move semantics, since a `const` object can't be moved from. This could hurt performance.

Comment: The answer is misleading : `square(2) += 5;` will be an error even if the return type is non-const double. The error has nothing to do with `const` in the return type.

Comment: square(2) += 5; results in an error anyway, regardless of const being there or not

Comment: @Nawaz: You're right (for built-in types); perhaps I shouldn't have tried to demonstrate what this `const` might actually achieve, and just focussed on why you don't want it.

Comment: @Nawaz: I hope the wording is less misleading now.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a "const function". It is a function which returns a value that is `const`. A "const function" only applies to member functions, and then the `const` goes on the *right*, after the parameter list.

The utility of this for a simple value type is dubious. However, if you were returning a reference to `const` or a `const` pointer, or something else, then it could have merit.

The only thing that returning a `const` of a simple type by value does is make sure that it can't be captured by non-`const` r-value reference in C++11. Otherwise, they'll just copy the value and be on their way.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give, and for any POD type, it makes little sense, but for more complex types it can make sense:-

```
const SomeClass &SomeFunction ();
```

which returns a reference to a const object.

Comment: Not the best example- this return type looks like `T& SomeFunction()` with `T` being `const SomeClass`. If we were talking pointers, it would look like `const SomeClass* SomeFunction()` while the OP is asking about cases like `SomeClass* const SomeFunction()`.

Comment: What if it's a POD type and you return by reference?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: references to PODs would behave the same as a reference to a class, so a const reference would be (usually) unchangeable by the caller. The returned type in these cases is a reference to something.

Comment: Which means the statement "In the example you give, and for any POD type, it makes little sense", is wrong. It doesn't matter if it is or isn't a POD, what matters is whether you return by value or not.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Hmmm....just trying out some stuff and you're right, returning a class by value can also lose the const. I can't find any way to prevent copying to non-const objects.

Answer (score 0):

A const function with const before the return value is usually used where the function returns a pointer (or perhaps a reference) to say that it will only return const pointers.  This one returns a double and that means it only returns doubles that are const.

Answer (score -1):

It returns a const double type variable.

If you do it like this, most compilers give a warning if you try to assign the returned value to a double type.